# decoding an array of objects in swift

Tags: swift, swift5

I have an array of objects

```
{"total_rows":5,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"index","key":"index","value":{"rev":"4-8655b9538706fc55e1c52c913908f338"}},
{"id":"newpage","key":"newpage","value":{"rev":"1-7a27fd343ff98672236996b3fe3abe4f"}},
{"id":"privacy","key":"privacy","value":{"rev":"2-534b0021f8ba81d09ad01fc32938ce15"}},
{"id":"secondpage","key":"secondpage","value":{"rev":"2-65847da61d220f8fc128a1a2f1e21e89"}},
{"id":"third page","key":"third page","value":{"rev":"1-d3be434b0d3157d7023fca072e596fd3"}}
]}
```

that I need too fit in struct and then decode in swift. My current code is:

```
struct Index: Content {

    var total_rows: Int
    var offset: Int
   // var rows: [String: String] // I don't really know what I am doing here 

}
```

and the router (using vapor)

```
router.get("/all") { req -> Future<View> in
        let docId = "_all_docs"
        print(docId)
        let couchResponse = couchDBClient.get(dbName: "pages", uri: docId, worker: req)
        guard couchResponse != nil else {
            throw Abort(.notFound)
        }

        print("one")
        return couchResponse!.flatMap { (response) -> EventLoopFuture<View> in
            guard let data = response.body.data else { throw Abort(.notFound) }

            print(data)

            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let doc = try decoder.decode(Index.self, from: data)

            let allDocs = Index(
                total_rows: doc.total_rows,
                offset: doc.offset
                //rows: doc.rows
            )
            print("test after allDocs")
            return try req.view().render("index", allDocs)
        }
    }
```

to summarise all is fine for the first level (total rows and offset are int and properly decoded) but how can I include in my structure the rows: array and assign thee parsed values to it ?

Comment: If your `Index` conforms to `Codable` (or `Decodable`), which I guess it does, based on your expectation to be decoded by `JSONDecoder`, then your `rows` would be an array of `Row` structs that are also decodable, for which their `value` would be another decodable etc. I hope that this makes sense...

Comment: @Alladinian could you share an example in the answer? very new to swift so I appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right road, you just need to keep going.

```
struct Index: Decodable {
    var total_rows: Int
    var offset: Int
    var rows: [Row]
}
```

Then you define a Row:

```
struct Row: Decodable {
    var id: String
    var key: String
    var value: Value
}
```

It's not really clear what a Value is in this context, but just to keep the structure.

```
struct Value: Decodable {
    var rev: String
}
```

And that's all.

```
let index = try JSONDecoder().decode(Index.self, from: jsonData)
```

Comment: awesome! one question thou: how would. populate these 3 structures? at the moment I have  let allDocs = Index(
                total_rows: doc.total_rows,
                offset: doc.offset,
                rows: doc.rows // this s obviously wrong as it is 
            )  thanks

Comment: tried      let doc = try decoder.decode(Index.self, from: data)
            
            let allDocs = Index(
                total_rows: doc.total_rows,
               offset: doc.offset,
               rows: doc.rows
            )
            print("test after allDocs")
            return try req.view().render("index", allDocs)
        }.   but I get Argument type 'Index' does not conform to expected type 'Encodable'

Comment: @devnull in the answer above `index` is of type `Index` already so there is no need to create another object `allDocs`, use `index` directly instead.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks I did that so now I have   let index = try JSONDecoder().decode(Index.self, from: data)
            
            return try req.view().render("index", index) but still get Argument type 'Index' does not conform to expected type 'Encodable'

Comment: @devnull Change Index and Row to conform to Codable instead

Comment: @JoakimDanielson this did it thank you ! you are awesome !